# jmeter response times using Response Time over Time

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, response-time

I'm new to JMeter (with a solid 5 days experience!) and so would like a little guidance if that's ok.  I've been trawling through the jmeter help and I did search (prior to submitting this request) for other response times questions, however I don't know enough to identify whether they're relevant or not - so I do apologise if this is the request is a duplication of a previous query.

My environment:
JMeter v2.11
JRE v7
Remote Oracle 12 DB

I am performance testing a system that will submit messages into a receiving component.

I have a requirement that states that the system can handle 2000 messages per hour (or 2000/3600 = 0.56 submissions/second)

So I have some beanshell samplers all ready setup to inject a single SOAP/XML message to emulate the submissions.

The beanshell samplers sit within a thread group object with settings as follows:

Thread Count: 1
Loop Count: 2000
StartTime: 2015/03/01 13:00:00
EndTime: 2015/03/01 14:00:00
Duration: 3600

I was thinking of using the 'Response Times over Time' plugin to verify the submission rate of 0.56/second - does this make sense if I specify the start/end times and the duration for the execution run with my thread group settings?  I need to verify the response time for EACH of the 2000 submissions is <=0.56/seconds.

Can anyone tell me if I have the correct approach defined and if not - can you point me in the correct direction?

Many thanks - I appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> **Elapsed time** . JMeter measures the elapsed time from just before sending the request to just after the last response has been received. JMeter does not include the time needed to render the response, nor does JMeter process any client code, for example Javascript.
>
> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
> The formula is: Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).

What you're talking about (2000 requests per hour or 0.56 requests per second) is rather throughput than response time so I would recommend:

1. [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) - to set exact desired load
2. [Transactions per Second](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) listener - to visualize it

In regards to setting test duration, you can just leave `3600` there, start and end time inputs are more for scheduling than for test duration. Alternative option is [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller).